# Failing to save Hosted Web App project in VS2015

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2015, web-application

When trying to create a new "Hosted Web App" UWP project in VS 2015 Enterprise Update 2, it seems to create the project (the Solution Explorer shows the files) but when I try and launch it, it says its needs to be saved before I can add a project.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Lcx.png]

So I click "Save" and choose the location to save it as, but when I hit that save button comes up.

[image]
It will create the folder for the solution, but then do nothing else.

The files I see in Solution Explorer are located in the "Temporary Projects" folder in AppData.

**EDIT:** Copying the files out of "Temporary Projects" and opening the solution form there works perfectly, just not the easiest workflow.

Comment: Try performing a repair "installation" of Visual Studio. This is possible from the normal Add/remove programs list.

Comment: @DanielB just tried this, issue still happening